# Tensorflow : data pipeline error at tf.train.shuffle_batch

Tags: tensorflow, shuffle

I am implementing a data pipline to a CNN implemented in tensorflow.

My pipeline working perfectly as follows.

```
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(image)
png_im = tf.image.decode_png(value, no_channels)
cropped = tf.random_crop(png_im , size)
batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([cropped ], batch_size=batch_size,             
capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
```

But when I want to add labels to this as follows;

```
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(image)
png_im = tf.image.decode_png(value, no_channels)

key, value = reader.read(label)
png_lb = tf.image.decode_png(value, no_channels)

(cropped_im, cropped_lb) = tf.random_crop_images_and_labels(png_im, png_lb, size)
imbatch, lbbatch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([cropped_im, cropped_lb], batch_size=batch_size,             
capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
```

My code is giving floowing error at tf.train.shuffle_batch;

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_2_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 20, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_UINT8], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]
```

No of images are 6400, batch size is 20.

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: what are the values of capacity and min_after_dequeue?

Comment: capacity = 1000 + batch_size*3, min_after_dequeue = 1000